# Select value from root node in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSL variable `prdxml` which holds an XML like this

```
    <node id="2939" parentID="2938" level="3" writerID="0" >
  <data alias="itemNumbers">,3101056,8261247,</data>
  <data alias="pass_word">akspass</data>
  <data alias="logo">/media/41532/inner-logo01.png</data> 
</node>
```

How can I select id(id="2939") which is in the root node from this variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the XML structure of an Umbraco node (pre-v4.5).

To access any of the attributes on an Umbraco node, you can use the `@` symbol like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$prdxml/@id" />
<xsl:value-of select="$prdxml/@parentID" />
```

To access properties you've defined on an Umbraco node, you'll use something like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$prdxml/data[@alias='pass_word']" />    
<xsl:value-of select="$prdxml/data[@alias='logo']" />
```

Umbraco have a whole section on their wiki here; http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/xslt ; with examples on how to traverse their XML with XPATH.

***-- edit to address comments --***

A working version of my XSLT is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets">

<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    Current Page ID : <xsl:value-of select="$currentPage/@id" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Possible reasons why this may not display on your page could be :

- `<xsl:param name="currentPage" />` is removed from your XSLT.
- The XSLT isn't bound to a Macro.
- The Macro isn't featured on a Template.
- The Template isn't assigned to your Node.
- The Node hasn't been published.

Comment: You were right about umbraco.But the code is not working for me.any idea?

Comment: How are you obtaining the source XML? Can we see the `$prdxml` declaration?

Comment: Actually its currentpage element in umbraco.I just refferred it here as prdxml for those who are not familiar with umbraco

Comment: Ahh, thought it might be that but didn't want to confuse the issue with assumptions. `$currentPage/@id` should do the trick.

Comment: actually i had tried the same before posting this question,but not working

Comment: It's a pretty standard piece of code for Umbraco XSLT, I just tested and it works fine (see my amended answer). I suspect something else is preventing it from showing. Does any text in your XSLT end up showing on the HTML page?

Comment: You were right the code is correct.actually i tried xsl copy instead of xsl value.But right now also i cant find why that xsl copy not worked.any way thanks for the greate help

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using XSLT 1.0.

For doing something like that you have to rely on the extension function node-set(). But because is an extension function its availability is dependent of the XSLT processor that you are using.

For example, in xsltproc, saxon you could use something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="_prdxml">
        <node id="2939" parentID="2938" level="3" writerID="0" >
            <data alias="itemNumbers">,3101056,8261247,</data>
            <data alias="pass_word">akspass</data>
            <data alias="logo">/media/41532/inner-logo01.png</data> 
        </node>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="prdxml" select="exsl:node-set($_prdxml)" />
        <!-- Now you can navigate through the prdxml node set -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$prdxml/node[@id = '2939']" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you are using the Microsoft XSLT Processor you have to change the namespace of the extension functions to

```
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
```